# Will I get feedback after raising a moderator flag?

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes, serial-voting

I raised a moderator flag last week, since I got some revenge downvotes. The flag was marked as helpful with a comment: "We'll take a look." But after that it seems nothing happened and I'm still getting the weird downvotes.

Will I get a feedback or result about it? Such as, the moderator has checked them, they're all normal downvotes, so nothing needs to be done. Or it just takes a long time to handle, so I should just wait? Or the moderator has taken some actions, but the result won't be informed.

[EDIT]

The downvotes were reversed at Jan 12 '17; without any notification.

---

<sup>Additional information:</sup>

<sup>I think they were revenge downvotes, because I started to get them after I closed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707347/using-double-instead-of-static-castdouble) (it has been deleted). And I've been a user of Stack Overflow for 2 years and never got such kind of weird downvotes before.</sup>

<sup>I know about the reversal script, but it doesn't catch them. Precisely, it caught the first 3 downvotes. But after that I started to get 1 or 2 downvotes at the same time, no more than 3. This happens every 2 or 3 days. And there might be a sock-puppeting since I often got 2 downvotes on the same post at the same time. I think the reversal script couldn't catch such kind of downvotes.</sup>

<sup>Over the lost reputation, I really want to know what I can do to stop it. It really makes me sick and depressed.</sup>

Comment: There are tons of duplicates for revenge downvote questions... If griefers make you sick getting off internet for some time may be good solution, otherwise ignore and move on. Moderators will not report "user X was found to be #$#$#" (and generally it is not recommended to single out users on meta too) - so I would not expect more feedback than standard "we'll take a look".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes I know it's an ordinary internet issue. I wonder how the community will handle with the case, and is there something could I do for it. So I have nothing to do with it, should just ignore and go on? And it's not the issue should be asked for moderator attention?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Just because it is common on the internet doesn't make it acceptable behavior. Rudeness, revenge votes, stalking etc is unacceptable on SO. The solution is to remove the "griefers" from the internet, not the other way around.

Comment: @Lundin So what is your suggestion - songyuanyao need to get depressed over it? Hunt downvoter in RL? Start revenge-revenge downvotes? To my understanding songyuanyao done all they can/should do and should consider issue closed for them.

Comment: _"It really makes me sick and depressed"_ -- that's a real problem, but it can't be solved by Stack Overflow. It's not healthy for you or anyone to engage in a public forum, and especially an Internet-based one, if relatively inconsequential behavior from a lone and anonymous individual is affecting you emotionally or physically.

Comment: These kinds of negative feelings can do genuine harm to you in the long run; that such other people exist is inevitable, so if their meaningless actions are that harmful to you, you should reconsider your participation. Much better though: recognize the behavior as the meaningless behavior it is, and shrug it off without letting it hurt you. Both you and the community will be better off for it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Flag so that moderators can ban them, end of story?

Comment: @Lundin I still can't get what you are suggesting. OP already flagged that behavior. So you clearly trying to recommend something else in addition... Again sorry for not understanding, have a good weekend.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes I know it's not easy to be solved, even confirm the behavior is legitimate or not is difficult. I just want to know the border line and ethics here, it's important for me to know that such behaviors are not allowed and we're trying to eliminate them, even though it's not an easy thing technically and practically. Thanks for your suggestion, I still believe StackOverflow is a fair place, other than many other public forums, that's why I like to spend a lot time to participate in.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Moderators cannot reverse votes; we have to escalate these situations to the Community Team.

When we come across your flag, providing it has merit, we will mark your flag as "helpful" (to clear it from our queue), then place it in the CM queue for *them* to take a look and reverse any votes (if applicable).

That's the state of your flag now; we've passed it onto the CM team. You won't hear from anyone again regarding the flag; but will be able to see when action has been taken, because the down votes will have been removed.

Comment: Other than reversing votes, could I expect the behavior could be stopped? Sorry if it's overcurious.

Comment: That depends entirely on whether the votes were clearly targeted or if you just happened to receive downvotes over time.

Comment: @BoltClock So something might happen, depending on the confirmation result about the downvotes. Thanks, it makes me clearer now. And thanks for the explanation about the processing and status, Matt.

Comment: Isn't the last sentence only true if the community team agrees that there's something abusive going on, or would they send a notice saying "we looked and the votes are legit" if they decided otherwise?

Comment: @DanNeely: No, the last sentence is true regardless. If the CM team see nothing untoward, they **won't** send a "we looked and the votes are legit" message to the original flagger.

Comment: In which case the action taken (do nothing) won't be visible, and remains indistinguishable from 'not reviewed yet' which was my point.

Answer (score 20):

> Update: a moderator answered and stated that your flag still is waiting for processing. Still, I'm leaving my answer as a general comment.

I don't know what is going on with your flag. But generally:

Four downvotes is *very* little to go by. Even if it is revenge downvoting by that one specific user (and it could be, looking at their "daily", "weekly" and "monthly" downvote counts, which match perfectly with your downvotes - although we will never know for sure) the person could argue that they saw something legitimately wrong in your posts.

In cases like this, I recommend you flag, and then laugh it off. Someone pathetic enough to strategically downvote someone else over a longer period of time is punished enough by their own issues.

If it goes on for a month or more, you can flag again: evidence will be more unanimous then.

For the moment, your four downvotes can be offset by *one* upvote, gaining which will be no problem for you.

Comment: Yes, the downvotes is not so much (more than 4, but less than 10). Over the lost reputation, I just want it to be stopped. (I might be too sensitive.) Anyway, thanks for your answer, it makes me more settling now.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you get feedback from all flags under your user, Activity tab. To the top right there's a box called "Impact", click on "x Helpful flags. This information is only visible to you (and moderators).

You will see all your flags and their status. When a flag was approved & resolved, it gets set as "helpful". When a flag is rejected, it gets set to "disputed" (in case it was a flag handled by user moderators, and they didn't agree) or "rejected" in case a diamond moderator rejected the flag. Sometimes you get a manually written line by a diamond moderator as feedback.

Even in the case when a flag escalates to the Community Team (SO employees) as in this case, you still end up with the flag status ultimately getting either "helpful" or "declined" status, though it may take longer time for complex matters.