# Serial voting not reversed, but flag marked as helpful

Tags: discussion, flags, serial-voting

Two weeks ago, I was serial downvoted:

[image: downvotes]

I waited a day, but the script didn't reversed the downvotings. Following [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857)

> If the 24 hours has already passed and the suspicious votes have not been reversed, you can then flag one of your posts and explain what happened so a moderator can look into it. It is generally preferred that you avoid asking about them on a site's Meta since details of the investigation cannot be divulged and you won't actually get any information that will be useful to other members of the community.

I flagged one of the downvoted questions for moderator intervention:

[image: flagged question]

Today the flag was marked as helpful, but the downvoting was not reversed.

Did I do anything wrong? Could I do anything more? Does it mean, that it was no serial voting?

Comment: Might not be serial downvoting, which requires the votes to come from one user.  Or that user might have socks.  Either way, the mod marked the flag as helpful to not penalize you, but they might not have anything else to say about the matter (their tools can show if there is evidence of targeted voting, and they may not have revealed any).

Comment: @Will no need to overcomplicate things. Some of serial downvotes I've got few months ago were confirmed as such by SE dev team but still are waiting in line to get invalidated. This can _really_ take long (I don't know why and frankly I don't care to know, these details may be too complicated to waste my time on learning them)

Comment: Bear in mind there appears to of been [some issues with the daily scripts lately](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335880/542251). This could be the issue, if it is, it should be resolved automatically at some point

Comment: so yes, latest comment form Oded, this is still an issue and might be the root cause of your problem

Comment: just to cheer you up, I had the same issue 1 month ago, flagged one of my posts and the day after the serial downvoting was reversed _and_ the user was deleted. Funny thing is I was downvoted 6 times, and I know almost for sure that the user was deleted because the guy upvoted me once and so I only regained 12-10 => 2 points. But justice has been done.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your flag is marked helpful when it is seen by a moderator. When it comes to serial-voting-invalidation, all a moderator can do is escalate the problem to the Community Team.

You're currently at the stage where a moderator has seen your flag  (flag marked helpful), but the Community Team has not processed the escalation (votes invalidated).

Also, apologies for your flag taking 2 weeks to process... there's currently a large backlog of "for moderator attention" flags we're only just starting to get control over.

... see also [Will I get feedback after raising a moderator flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322946/will-i-get-feedback-after-raising-a-moderator-flag)

Comment: I wonder if there's someplace in the UI that could give a hint about the need to escalate? Perhaps right next to where it shows that the flag was marked helpful?

Comment: Do you (the mods) escalate flags often enough to have separate "helpful" and "escalated" statuses?